# Looping though collection inside other collection and LINQ lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Here I'm selecting descriptions from all FactoryOption with an Header of "TRANSMISSION"

```
tOptions = _vDetails.fOptions
                    .Where(x => (x.header != null && x.header.Value.ToUpper() == "TRANSMISSION"))
                    .Select(x => x.description)
                    .SelectMany(x => x);
```

If the header is null I would like to search for the header in ambiguous options which matches to  "TRANSMISSION"

Something like the following :

```
foreach (var fOptions in _vDetails.fOptions)
{
    if (fOptions.header != null && fOptions.header.Value.ToUpper() == "TRANSMISSION")
    {
        tOptions = fOptions.description;
    }
    else if (fOptions.ambiguousOption != null)
    {
        foreach (var ambiguousOption in fOptions.ambiguousOption)
        {
            if (ambiguousOption.header != null && ambiguousOption.header.Value.ToUpper() == "TRANSMISSION")
            {
                newseq = tOptions.Concat(ambiguousOption.description);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to change existing LINQ lambda expression for iterating through `fOptions.ambiguousOption` could someone please suggest.

Comment: could you provide some sample data so i can test my linq expression on ?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do... do you want to change your Foreach statement to a Linq statement?

Comment: What type is `factoryOption.description`?  A string or list?  If it's a list, of what type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly I think you just want to do something like this:

```
var result = options.SelectMany(o => IsTransmissionHeader(o.header) ? o.description :
                                         o.ambigousOptions == null || !o.ambigousOptions.Any(x => IsTransmissionHeader(x.header)) ? new string[] { } : 
                                         o.ambigousOptions.First(x => IsTransmissionHeader(x.header)).description)
                    .Where(d => d.Any());
```

I added a static method to check the header:

```
public static bool IsTransmissionHeader(Header header)
{
    return header != null && header.Value != null && header.Value.ToUpper() == "TRANSMISSION"
}
```

This will return `IEnumerable<string>`. If you want a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>` change the `SelectMany` to `Select`.

**EDIT:**

To get all *Transmission* description values from `ambigousOptions` you need to change the last line so it looks like this:

```
var result = options.SelectMany(o => IsTransmissionHeader(o.header) ? o.description :
                                         o.ambigousOptions == null || !o.ambigousOptions.Any(x => IsTransmissionHeader(x.header)) ? new string[] { } :
                                         o.ambigousOptions.Where(x => IsTransmissionHeader(x.header)).SelectMany(x => x.description));
```

Comment: The above statement will return a List of the descriptions. If the outer option header is TRANSMISSION it takes the description otherwise it checks the inner options. Which part do you not understand?

Comment: The Where clause is just filtering any empty strings that appear in cases where the outer header is not "TRANSMISSION" and the inner options are all null or none of their headers are "TRANSMISSION"

Comment: I updated answer again. Can you let me know if this works for you?

Comment: Are you using `var` in declaration? Or what line are you getting the error on?

Comment: I added another null check to the `IsTransmissionHeader` method. Can you see if this fixes the exception?

Comment: I am trying to get all possible values from ambiguousOptions as well, right now it just gets first item which matches

Comment: I updated answer to show how to get all `ambiguousOptions`. Can you remember to accept answer if it has solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want. Here I concatenate the descriptions from `FactoryOption` that have a matching header with the descriptions from `AmbiguousOption` that have a matching header.

```
var descriptions = details.SelectMany(d => d.FactoryOptions.Where(f => f.Header == "TRANSMISSION").Select(f => f.Description)
    .Concat(d.FactoryOptions.SelectMany(f => f.AmbiguousOptions.Where(a => a.Header == "TRANSMISSION").Select(a => a.Description))));
```

**Update**
Answer above is for when you start with a collection of `Detail`. If you start with a single `Detail` then you can do:

```
_vehicleDetails.FactoryOptions.Where(f => f.Header == "TRANSMISSION").Select(f => f.Description)
    .Concat(_vehicleDetails.FactoryOptions.SelectMany(f => f.AmbiguousOptions.Where(a => a.Header == "TRANSMISSION").Select(a => a.Description)));
```

Comment: Does my answer not work for you? If not, in what case is it failing?